# table background image not set in google chrome

Tags: html, css, django, cross-browser

html template for print page:

```
<table style="width:128px;height:293px;background-position:center;" id="human-body"  background="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/human.png" border="0">
<tr><td>some data</td></tr>
</table>
```

This is my html to print the image,when i click print button,the print page preview is open in Firefox with this background image, but in chrome the image is missing.What would be the problem.

The whole thing is no background image is applied for print out page in both browser.

Comment: Use CSS, not some outdated attribute.

Comment: do you see any 404s in the console?

Comment: @karthikr,console its 200 no 404s

Comment: firefox is probably loading from its cache. Check if the url generated is valid - That is, access the URL directly from the browser and see

Comment: you mean now you can't see the image in both the browsers? do you know Urdu?

Comment: @karthikr ,yesterday we discussed about this,i corrected the css issue,now my problem is the same but in console it returned 404 for image alone

Comment: that means the image is not accessible. Did you change the filename, or move it to a different location?

Comment: image location also corrected.In console the print template is showing 200 but if i directly checked the url in browser it is giving this error "Exception Type: ValueError at /member/template/
Exception Value: The view incident.views.report_template didn't return an HttpResponse object."

Comment: @karthikr,any update on this?

Comment: does this template have access to `STATIC_URL` ? What is the background-image url it is generating?

Comment: template have access to STATIC_URL,background-image url is static/images/human.png

Comment: @karthikr still issue was not solved,do you have any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<table style="width:128px;height:293px;background-position:center;background-image:url(images/human.png);border:0;" id="human-body">
```

Your might check your directories if your css is in another folder and your image is in another folder then you may change your URL and add "../" at the beginning.

This might help you!

Comment: please post some images regarding the outputs in Chrome and Firefox

Comment: ,while print preview in Firefox the background is apply   and if it printed,the print out is with out background.In chrome while preview the image gets loaded and disappear,no image in print out.

Comment: The one with image is in Firefox,that gets vanish when print out is taken

Comment: is your css is in other directory or in the same as of image?

Comment: Both are from same /static/ directory like this static/styles/custom.css and static/images/person.png

Comment: try adding "../" in you URL in the beginning

Comment: Sorry to say,it is also not working.Roughly  what would be the cause of this issue.

Comment: acutally "../" this means to go back one directory.